# Structure with category setting

Tags: categories, listing

OK, it's more a philosophic question that a programming question, but at the end it will have a huge impact on code...

I have 5 main product, a,b,c,d,e

those 5 products have options
those products can belong to multiple category

So the end, i should show the product a, with below, option of product a witch is a1, a2, a3, a4 and below, the other products that belong to the same category as a, so it can be, x, y, z.

So it look like

- a

  - a1
  - a2
  - a3
  - a4
- x
- y
- z

How should i manage categories, should i create a category witch name is option for a or there is a better way. Organising is not my stongest point, but good organization can lead to easy coding..

thanks in advance

---

idea, if i can control the ID of the post created, i will create product a as id=100 and all option as product option a1 : id-101. option a2 : id=201 and so on ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm pretty sure i missunderstood you...*

#### Approach: Categories & Terms (built in taxonomies)

You have got categories (hierarchical built in taxonomy) & terms (non-hierarchical built in taxonomy). You can also assign terms to categories. So i'd say, you can take the following approach using the built in taxonomies:

- shoes (parent category)
- - boots (child category)
- - sneakers (child category)
- - other shoes (default child category)

and then use terms inside additional categories like:

- color (parent cateogry)
- - cyan (term)
- - magenta (term)
- - yellow (term)
- - black (term)
- laces (parent category)
- - long (term)
- - medium (term)
    and so on ...

This would give you the ability to list all shoes on a category page. Then you can further list all sneakers on one page. You can also list all shoes that got long laces and red color.

#### Templates

Take a look at (for eg.) [here](http://www.wpmods.com/query-multiple-taxonomies-in-wp-3-1) for more information about the query for different archive (category/term) pages and how to query/retrieve multiple taxonomies at one page.